A reference for the fact that the second cohomology of the full Poincare algebra is zero
S. Weinberg in his book "The quantum theory of fields" vol. I says in page 86 that the full Poincare algebra is not semi-simple but its central charges can be eliminated (as he showed in the book).
For every finite dimensional semi-simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ one can show $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{K})=0$. But as Weinberg has mentioend  the full  Poincare algebra is not semi-simple.
I need a reference for this fact that the second cohomology of the full Poincare algebra is zero. I would really appreciate if someone could help me about it.

A perhaps very illuminating and nice argument is given in the thesis of Nesta van der Schaaf: https://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/Nesta.pdf . Please take a look at Section 5.2. You get a full proof for your question, and in addition, a construction of the universal cover of the Poincare group.
On the Other hand, I can only recommend this thesis, it is written wonderfully for taking care of aspects of Projective Representations.

Thank you so much for your help. It was be really helpful and I needed it so much for projective representations as well. Appreciate you very much.

You are welcome. I am writing a review on them, with a special focus on the 3 famous groups in physics: Heisenberg, Galilei, Poincaré. I will post the link here in comment or edit the answer, when it is done/on arxiv.

Dear @ProphetX , I really appreciate your help. I look forward for them.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2412.04695
